# Play framework Javascript router not working for controller in different directory

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework-2.0

This question is concerned with the less verbose way of giving Play's javascript router

[Less Verbose way of generating Play 2's javascript router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012703/less-verbose-way-of-generating-play-2s-javascript-router)

I have two route mappings in my routes file:

```
GET     /attachments/:id/content      com.application.controllers.File.getOrderContent(id:String)

POST    /drive                        com.application.controllers.myapp.Drive.createDrive()
```

I have the non-verbose Javascript router code in a scala file:

```
val routeCache = {
  import routes._
  val jsRoutesClass = classOf[routes.javascript]
  val controllers = jsRoutesClass.getFields().map(_.get(null))
  controllers.flatMap { controller =>
    controller.getClass().getDeclaredMethods().map { action =>
        action.invoke(controller).asInstanceOf[play.core.Router.JavascriptReverseRoute]
    }
  }
}

def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(routeCache:_*)).as("text/javascript")
}
```

I am getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Drive' of undefined" when I am using

```
jsRoutes.com.application.controllers.myapp.Drive.createDrive().ajax({...
```

whereas

*jsRoutes.com.application.controllers.File.getOrderContent().ajax({...* works **fine**.

Any thoughts on why the com.application.controllers.myapp.Drive path is not recognized by the router? I thought all the paths in the routes directory would be included in jsRoutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one one routes object and one javascript generated per package. So in your case you will have `controllers.(routes|javascript)` containing all the controller routes for the controllers in the package `controllers` and a separate `controllers.myapp.(routes|javascript)` for those in `controllers.myapp`

You can find the generated sources under `target/scala-[version]/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java` and `target/scala-[version]/src_managed/main/controllers/myapp/routes.java`.